# re.finditer isn't finding substrings

Tags: python, python-re

I currently have a string and a substring that's extracted from that string. I'm trying to find the start and end positions of the substring within the original string, and have found useful answers on this community that advise to use Python's regular expression library.

I've tried something like:

```
>>> string = "'Co - carcinogenic effect of retinyl acetate on forestomach carcinogenesis of male F344 rats induced \
... with butylated hydroxyanisole . The potential modifying effect of retinyl acetate ( RA ) on butylated \
... hydroxyanisole ( BHA ) - induced rat forestomach tumorigenesis was examined . Male F344 rats , 5 weeks of age , \ 
... were maintained on diet containing 1 % or 2 % BHA by weight and simultaneously on drinking water supplemented \
... with RA at various concentrations ( w / v ) for 52 weeks . In groups given 2 % BHA , although marked hyperplastic \
... changes of the forestomach epithelium were observed in all animals , co - administration of 0 . 25 % RA \
... significantly ( P less than 0 . 05 ) increased the incidence of forestomach tumors ( squamous cell papilloma and \
... carcinoma ) to 60 % ( 9 / 15 , 2 rats with carcinoma ) from 15 % ( 3 / 20 , one rat with carcinoma ) in the group \
... given RA - free water . In rats given 1 % BHA , RA co - administered at a dose of 0 . 05 , 0 . 1 , 0 . 2 or 0 . 25 \
... % showed a dose - dependent enhancing effect on the development of the BHA - induced epithelial hyperplasia . \
... Tumors , all papillomas , were induced in 3 rats ( 17 % ) with 0 . 25 % RA and in one rat ( 10 % ) with 0 . 05 % \
... RA co - administration . RA alone did not induce hyperplastic changes in the forestomach . These findings \
... indicate that RA acted as a co - carcinogen in the BHA forestomach carcinogenesis of the rat .'"
...
>>> substring = "on butylated hydroxyanisole ( BHA ) - induced rat forestomach tumorigenesis was examined . Male \
... F344 rats , 5 weeks of age , were maintained on diet containing 1 % or 2 % BHA by weight and simultaneously on \
... drinking water supplemented with RA at various concentrations ( w / v ) for 52 weeks . In groups given 2 % BHA \
... , although marked hyperplastic changes of the forestomach epithelium were observed in all animals , co - \
... administration of 0 . 25 % RA significantly ( P less than 0 . 05 ) increased the incidence of forestomach \
... tumors ( squamous cell papilloma and carcinoma ) to 60 % ( 9 / 15 , 2 rats with carcinoma ) from 15 % ( 3 / 20 \
... , one rat with carcinoma ) in the group given RA - free water . In rats given 1 % BHA , RA co - administered at \
... a dose of 0 . 05 , 0 . 1 , 0 . 2 or 0 . 25 % showed a dose - dependent enhancing effect on the development of \
... the BHA"
...
>>> import re
>>> printx([(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(substring, string)]
[]
>>> print(string.index(substring))
189
```

As you can see, the substring exists within string, but the use of `re.finditer` is returning an empty list (i.e., `None`). Does anybody know why this behavior occurs, and how I can fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: `substring` is not a regex that matches the substring you want, because it contains special characters. Try `re.escape(substring)` instead.

Comment: That said, why not just use the second version which works without regexes? You can find the starting index and then add `len(substring)` to get the ending index.